# What's the difference between System Interfaces User Interfaces?

Tags: testing, srs

Upon checking Software requirements specification in wikipedia, in example organization of SRS found out that System Interfaces and User Interfaces are two different thing.

Answer (score 1):

user interface is what the actual users(us) sees in the 
application(the buttons, sliders, text boxs etc..)

while the system interface is the methods that an operating 
system provides to the application programs

Comment: Thnx Mr Amit Choudhary.